# Can I add or subtract pixels from this.props.style?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to position a plus button according to div's height. I have exported a button element and using in various components.
From a component, I am passing the height value of the div. My question is, can I subtract some pixels from the value I get?

I am able to successfully place the button according to the div's height. However, I want it some pixels less.

```
<ComponentName height='div height' ... />
```

In Component's file

```
interface Props {
  ...
  height: any;
}
```

and in css, I want to do something like this-

```
top: this.props.height - 5px;
```

Can we subtract the pixels from a height that I get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parseInt function.

```
parseInt(this.props.height) - 5;
```

Since this is ReactJS, I assume you only care about the value (style values that are numbers automatically have `px` appended when rendered).

You could pass a Number for `ComponentName` `height` prop and avoid parsing the value to a Number if you can avoid it.